# How can I insert title of article in revolution slider in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Good Morning,

I have a question about Revolution Slider. How can I insert the title of the article on slider?

I have Revolution Slider 5.0.6.

Bye!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Post Based Slider type.  In slides section, create a single slide (unless you want it to revolve) and add text/html and type {{title}} and choose the font/color you want.  For the background picture, you will need to goto media and select the specific picture and find the URL listed for it.  In Rev slider under edit slides, choose External URL for picture and paste that URL in.  Then add the slider to the Post and it should display the title where you added {{title}}.

Answer (score 1):

First, add new layer and you will see text/html, chose this text/html, and after this, there will be two icons, one green tick and another yellow one, click on this yellow one, then you will get all possible list

Screen shot is attached below:

[List of possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOhKo.png)

Comment: Might want to work on your grammar and punctuation, your answer is quite hard to read.

Comment: sorry for my grammar i just wan to describe you the process
have you got my point or not